# Store vector<file> in CStringArray?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, mfc

This is belong to visual studio 2013 (v120). How to convert this in visual studio 2010(v100)?

```
struct {
        bool operator()(const CString &a, const CString &b)
        {
            WIN32_FIND_DATA fa{0},fb{0};
            HANDLE h;

            h = FindFirstFile(a, &fa);
            if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) FindClose(h);
            h = FindFirstFile(b, &fb);
            if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) FindClose(h);

            return 1 == CompareFileTime(&fa.ftCreationTime, &fb.ftCreationTime);
        }
    } sortproc;
```

Two error:
First : h = FindFirstFile(b, &fb); 13   IntelliSense: identifier "fb" is undefined  c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\file cleaner\file cleaner\search.h 90  25  File Cleaner

Second: WIN32_FIND_DATA fa{0},fb{0};    12  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\file cleaner\file cleaner\search.h 85  21  File Cleaner

Comment: What is `file` actually?

Comment: Your code seems unrelated to your problem (although it's unclear what that problem is) and it's difficult to imagine what storing a `vector<file>` in an array of strings would mean.

Comment: I assume you want to iterate over your `std::vector<file>` and store the file names in the `CStringArray`. But what for ? You can get `wchar_t` from both, `CString` and `std::wstring`.

Comment: ok i improve the code.

Comment: But i need to store files in CStringArray. I need to process the files.

Comment: Why don't you do that then ? `CStringArray::Add(std::wstring::c_str())`

Comment: Please sir rewrite the code. Mean implement it?

Comment: As it's name suggests, `CStringArray` is an array of `CString`s. You can put _filenames_ into an `CStringArray` but you cannot put your `file` type into a `CstringArray`. It's not clear what you actually want.

Comment: Yes i want to put sort files name in CStringArray. And how to do that?

Comment: CStringArray myarray; ... myarray.Add("MyString"); etc. Read the documentation of CStringArray.

Comment: This seems to be duplicate or continuation of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043803/sort-files-according-to-creation-date You should explain that, it's not reasonable to throw some code and ask people to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort `CStringArray` (at least not easily), you have to convert it to `vector<wstring>` or `vector<string>` etc.

Use this to convert `CStringArray` to/from `vector<wstring>`:

```
CStringArray sa;
vector<wstring> vws;

vws.resize(0);  //CStringArray to vector<string>
for (int i = 0; i < sa.GetCount(); i++)
    vws.push_back((const wchar_t*)sa[i]);

sa.RemoveAll(); //vector<string> back to CStringArray
for (int i = 0; i < (int)vws.size(); i++)
    sa.Add(vws[i].c_str());
```

`CString` has a place in MFC, but `CStringArray` is not that important, you might do away with it and use `vector<CString>` instead:

```
vector<CString> vcs;
//fill vcs...

struct {
    bool operator()(const CString &a, const CString &b)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA fa{ 0 }, fb{ 0 };
        HANDLE h;

        h = FindFirstFile(a, &fa);
        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) FindClose(h);

        h = FindFirstFile(b, &fb);
        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) FindClose(h);

        return 1 == CompareFileTime(&fa.ftCreationTime, &fb.ftCreationTime);
    }
} sortproc;

sort(vcs.begin(), vcs.end(), sortproc);
```